# How to stop looping of pivot control in windows phone apps 8.1

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have 5 pivot items in my pivot control on reaching of 5th pivot item it shoould not loop again . I know that is not a best UX design and you cant stop pivot from looping . Just looking for some pivot methods hacks which help me out .

Comment: You can't. You can use `FlipView` or a horizontal `ListView` but you would need to recreate the pivot headers yourself.